# Find out only the recently added items in the list (python)

Tags: python, list

Is there a way to find out only the recent additions to the list? For example:

```
list1=['apple', 'mango', 'banana']
```

Now few items are added to the list.

```
list2=['apple','mango','banana','apple','mango','lemon']
```

I need to keep only the most recent addition i.e.

```
['apple','mango','lemon'].
```

Comment: how do you add an item to the list?

Comment: Please clarify whether you ever add to the list at the beginning or middle, or only at the end.

Comment: Iterate over `list1` and remove each item from `list2`

Comment: the items can be added at the beginning or middle, or only at the end randomly. @Passerby

Answer (score 3):

No, not without externally keeping track of those additions. Arrays have no concept of time - you can overwrite a value at any position in the array, or append to the end. You would need to cache recent additions somehow in a separate array.